# How do I ensure Android phonegap/cordova apps use Chrome webviews?

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova

I'm writing a game app that twists SVG graphics until they cry "Uncle!".  The program works OK on an iPad (safari/webkit) when hosted from a web server, for which no more need be said here.  It also works OK on an Android tablet when hosted from a web server, as long as a recent version of Chrome (like v.25 or later) is used.

The program doesn't access the internet at all, but plays with its SVG graphics, runs Javascript and stores status in HTML5 localStorage().

If I run the program on the "default browser" of older Android tablets the SVG graphics don't get handled correctly, thus my requirement for a recent version of Chrome on the tablet.

I have just created an APK for my app, and find that it doesn't use the Chrome browser when I install it on my really-new Android tablet.  Rather, it seems to use a browser embedded within the APK, or at least called from the APK for which remnant libraries exist in the tablet.

My aim with the APK is to make my code run displayed by a recent webkit browser, which seems to mean running in the Chrome environment.

For my question, I need to change something. But what?

- embed a Chrome browser in my APK?
- tell the APK to use the tablet's Chrome browser?
- give up using APK to distribute the program?
- ???

Do my dear readers have a clue for me?

Thanks,
Jerome.

Comment: Apps are limited to using the OS webview (both Android and IOS) which isn't the same as Safari or Chrome. Features/performance will be different. You might want to give details as to how SVG isn't handled properly.

Comment: @MorrisonChang is correct that the problem you are seeing is because Cordova uses the native Android WebView, which doesn't support SVG. There has been some discussion on the Cordova dev list about trying to use the Chrome view instead of the native Android WebView but so far it has required too much work for too little gain (not to mention incurring a big increase in file size since your APK would have to package the Chrome browser.) Some more info is here: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cordova-dev/201306.mbox/%3CCADVgkyOShF7-w_Fk654=dPNZOD2uQ1pFBGTf6fynHWZqEOu8Bw@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, I really do need the recent Chrome browser a this time.  I don't really have a link for you, but running the app in (any version of the "default" Android browser), (Chrome v.18, commonly found in low-end Android tablets) and (Chrome, v.25 or later) yield different results.  I'd have to run a debugger on the tablet to be sure, but sometimes the transform("rotate 90 0 0") doesn't work.  Even if I debugged things for, say, Chrome v.18 should I expect that my fix would not work for v.25 in "the future".  That is what we went to standards to eliminate...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I would recommend [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/), however, since 19th of March 2017, it has been declared EOL (more info below). Still, it's by far the most stable solution out there, our team currently uses it in a production application. Put simply, it packages a Chromium based webview inside your apk and it's backed by Intel. You can use it starting from Android 4.X.

Official sales pitch:

> Crosswalk is a web runtime for ambitious HTML5 applications. It provides all the features of a modern browser, combined with deep device integration and an API for adding native extensions. It is especially suited to mobile devices, with support for both Android and Tizen.

For **Cordova 4.0.0** and higher there is an official Crosswalk plugin, making it really easy to get up and running: https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

If you have your Cordova project running, all you need to do is

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview --save
```

to add the Crosswalk webview plugin. The next build will fetch all dependencies and package everything nicely.

**Android 4.4.x**

On Android 4.4 your hybrid app will run on a Chromium based WebView, however, it will be stuck on the same version forever (if I'm not mistaken it's Chromium 33). In my opinion it would be best to use Crosswalk here as well.

**Android 5.0+**

If you code for Android 5.0 and above, the Chromium WebView will be updated through Google Play. More info here: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/lollipop.html#WebView

**CrossWalk version 20 and up**

CrossWalk will drop support for Android 4.0.X starting with version 20. If you really need to keep 4.0.X in your support matrix, do not upgrade. I would recommend to build another APK for Android 5.X and above which no longer includes CrossWalk at all. [More info on this](https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/deprecate-40.html)

**Crosswalk v23 is the last release (EOL)**

Crosswalk has decided to release one last stable version in January of 2017, version 23. This ends official support for Crosswalk and leaves bugfixes and such to the community. More info in the [blogpost](https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/crosswalk-final-release.html)

**Notice!**

I found that running my mobile hybrid app had better graphical performance on Crosswalk than when I relied on the system webview (tested on a Sony Xperia ZL, which is on Android 5.x, so the webview is updated through the play store). Why that is, I've no idea yet, maybe Crosswalk configures the Webview in certain ways? This needs further investigation.

Comment: An update to this, as from android 4.4 (KitKat), chromium will be the driver behind WebView content, rejoice!

Comment: And even more updates, as of Android 5.0 (Lollipop), the Chromium WebView will be updated seperately from the OS. More info -> http://developer.android.com/about/versions/lollipop.html#WebView

Comment: Cordova v4+ now supports pluggable webviews so crosswalk can be easily used by installing a cordova plugin:
https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

Comment: Although I evaded the issue a long time ago, for a new development project I think that the crosswalk environment would solve my issues.  Being prodded to resolve this question, this answer seems most expansive and likely to succeed.  I put my vote here.

Comment: "I found that running my mobile hybrid app had better graphical performance on Crosswalk then when I relied on the system webview (tested on a Sony Xperia ZL). Why that is, I've no idea yet, maybe Crosswalk configures the Webview in certain ways? This needs further investigation.
" -> erm, Crosswalk basically packs chrome in the app. On < 4.4 [i think] Android is stuck with the webview that was shipped with, meaning an older version of Chromium. So, simply: it's normal that you get better performance with a newer version of a browser than with an old one

Comment: My ZL is on Android 5.0, so it's a Chromium webview updated from the Play store. I would agree with your statement if my ZL was stuck on Android 4.4 or less, even though newer can also mean more bloat. It's just undetermined at this point (can't investigate this further atm due to time constraints). Will edit this into my answer for clarification.

Comment: Crosswalk is stopped!

Comment: I'm facing a strange situation. My Meizu MX4 Pro has Lollipop 5.1.1. I've built my app and DevTools shows the WebView Chrome version is `40.0.2214.127`. Which is seriously outdated. Using Crosswalk I'm able to bump the version to `53`, but this contradicts what was said above, where Crosswalk shouldn't be included for 5.x and above. Which approach should work then?

Comment: Crosswalk has been dead for a long time now but the concept behind it is still relevant today. Is there any alternative to Crosswalk which *doesn't* use a native webview?

Answer (score 7):

try https://github.com/thedracle/cordova-android-chromeview
its a new project and needs more work but combines the chromeview project with cordova to embed chromium in a cordova android application

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a promising option: [Crosswalk + Cordova](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova_4.html).

Benefits:

- Use Cordova API
- Use Crosswalk API
- Cordova will use Crosswalk as its webview
- Crosswalk does not use the Android webview, its based on Chromium

Github repo: https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-cordova-android.

Comment: The link is down. [Could you please update your post?](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-cordova-android)

Comment: The repo has the latest info: https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-cordova-android

Comment: Crosswalk is stopped!

Answer (score 4):

**Updated answer for 2014**: [Android 4.4 and newer use Chrome webview by default](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview). This is currently based around Chrome version 30.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to launch the Chrome browser with a link to the appropriate site.

This isn't a great user experience, but might get you some of the way there.

You can check for and launch the Chrome Browser with something along the lines of:

```
    String url = "http://www.totallyawesomeurl.com";
    String packageName = "com.android.chrome";

    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    browserIntent.setPackage(packageName);
    browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    List<ResolveInfo> activitiesList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
            browserIntent, -1);
    if(activitiesList.size() > 0) {
        // Found the browser on the device, launch it
        context.startActivity(browserIntent);
    } else {
        // The browser isn't installed, so we should prompt the user to get
        Intent playStoreIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        playStoreIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+packageName));
        playStoreIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(playStoreIntent);
    }
```

It's worth noting that Chrome for Android is only available for ICS devices and above, so you might want to ensure you set the minimumTargetSDK to 14 and perhaps switch to using Opera for older version of Android if you site works in Opera which has package name "com.opera.browser"

Comment: My original idea was to wrap an HTML5 file with PhoneGap and use that path for an Android app.  Your suggestion here seems to be to call an existing Chrome and then use it, thru .setData() and .startActivity(), to fire up Chrome with a file I provide in the package.  Once I learn more about native Android programming, I can get there.  My Q: what of this "isn't a great user experience"?

Comment: I am not aware of a way you can tell Chrome to load a file from an application. I was referring to you hosting the site online and then opening Chrome with that URL. Regarding the user experience, it's bad to get a user to download an app from the play store to then send them to Chrome. Using a WebView is different, but it sounds like it doesn't support the features that you need :(

Answer (score -6):

It turns out that my Javascript was wrong.  Things work OK on old browsers when I avoid a certain bug.  I found it by being able to load an ancient version of Safari for Windows.

My problem was something like this:

```
var newValue = parseInt("030");
```

This returned 24, because "030" is base 8, right?

I changed things to force the base, and things are now OK:

```
var newValue = parseInt("030", 10);
```

Comment: JSHint would have told you about the missing radix parameter ;)

Comment: wrong posting place or SO bug? this answer has nothing to do with the question... moderation please?

Comment: Odd that this post should have been deleted.  I, the question author, put it here because finding the bug, where I didn't use the parseInt(val, radix) version, means I no longer need the answer to my original question.  I no longer need, or care, about my original question.

Comment: SO serves the need of community. When a question is asked and an answer is provided it might help others. This question became (gold) famous because many people are interested how to force a webview version in PhoneGap. Not because you made some bugs...

Comment: Alas!  I have a modest reputation, made almost entirely of asking interesting questions.  Not something on which to build a guru status, but I'll get by with some help from gentle SO commenters.